# Binding to an ObservableCollection to show the first X number of items c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

## Background Explanation

Okay so I'm currently binding a `ContextMenu` `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection` of lets say `TypeA`

*The following code is within the singleton class DataStore*

```
private ObservableCollection<TypeA> TypeACollection = new ObservableCollection<TypeA>();

public ObservableCollection<TypeA> GetTypeACollection
{
    get { return TypeACollection; }
}
public ObservableCollection<TypeA> GetFirstFiveTypeACollection
{
    get 
    {
        return TypeACollection.Take(5);
    }
}
```

Now I've already successfully bound an `ItemsControl` to `GetTypeACollection` with the following XAML code:

*The following code is within the MainWindow.xaml*

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="TypeAList" ItemsSource="{Binding GetTypeACollection, Source={StaticResource DataStore}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <User_Controls:TypeAUserControl Type="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This works as expected, showing the `TypeAUserControl`, correctly formatted as intended with the data from `TypeA`

Now when i try to repeat this on a `ContextMenu` `MenuItem` by binding the `ItemsSource` to `GetFirstFiveTypeACollection` i initially see the expected results however upon deleting a `TypeA` object the MainWindow `ItemsControl` is updated where the `ContextMenu` is not.

I believe this is due to the fact that the binding itself is between the `ContextMenu` and a 'new' `ObservableCollection<TypeA>` (as seen in `GetFirstFiveTypeAColletion` ).

I have also attempted this through use of an `IValueConverter`

*The following code is within the class ValueConverters*

```
public class ObservableCollectionTypeAResizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<TypeA> TypeACollection = value as ObservableCollection<TypeA>;

        return TypeACollection.Take(System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter));
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

## The XAML code I have tried.

*Using IValueConverter*

```
<MenuItem Header="First 5 Type A" Name="MI_FirstFiveTypeA" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DATA_STORE.GetTypeACollection, ConverterParameter=5,
            Converter={StaticResource ObservableCollectionTypeAResizeConverter}, 
            Source={StaticResource DataStore}}" 
/>
```

*Using GetFirstFiveTypeACollection*

```
<MenuItem Header="First 5 Type A" Name="MI_FirstFiveTypeA" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DATA_STORE.RecentTimers, Source={StaticResource DataStore}, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
/>
```

I've no idea what to try and do next or how i should be doing this, Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Edit

Okay so I have changed the following

*DataStore.cs*

```
private ObservableCollection<TimerType> TimerTypes = new ObservableCollection<TimerType>();

public ObservableCollection<TimerType> getTimerTypes
{
    get 
    { 
        return new ObservableCollection<TimerType>(TimerTypes.OrderByDescending(t => t.LastUsed)); 
    }
}
public ObservableCollection<TimerType> RecentTimers
{
    get 
    { 
        return new ObservableCollection<TimerType>(TimerTypes.OrderByDescending(t => t.LastUsed).Take(5)); 
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
//THIS IS IN THE ADD METHOD
TimerTypes.Add(timer);
NotifyPropertyChanged("getTimerTypes");
NotifyPropertyChanged("RecentTimers");
NotifyPropertyChanged("TimerTypes");

//THIS IS IN THE REMOVE METHOD
TimerTypes.Remove(Timer);
NotifyPropertyChanged("getTimerTypes");
NotifyPropertyChanged("RecentTimers");
NotifyPropertyChanged("TimerTypes");
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="TimersList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=getTimerTypes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
```

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
//Lists are populated in DataStore.cs before this.
DataContext = DataStore.DATA_STORE;
InitializeComponent();
```

*NotifyIcon.xaml*

```
<MenuItem Header="Recent Timers" Name="MIRecent" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentTimers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

*NotifyIcon.xaml.cs*

```
DataContext = DataStore.DATA_STORE;
InitializeComponent();
```

So everything binds correctly at start but when a `TimerType` is deleted the `PropertyChangedEventHandler` is always NULL. I thought this was a `DataContext` issue but I'm pretty sure I have the `DataContext` and all of the `Bindings` correct now?

## Singleton Instance Creation

```
private static readonly DataStore Instance = new DataStore();

private DataStore() { }

public static DataStore DATA_STORE
{
    get { return Instance; }
    set { }
}
```

Comment: You talk in code which is great, but what is the actual goal description? Maybe the question can be answered by a design which doesn't rely on the current architecture.

Comment: @OmegaMan So the application has a Taskbar icon with a Context Menu which contains an item 'Recent Timers' this should show up to 5 previous timers in order of their property 'LastUsed'. In the main window of the application there is a ItemsControl as a stackpanel, this should show all previous timers in order of property 'LastUsed'. Each item in the stackpanel has a Context Menu allowing the User to 'Start', 'Rename' or 'Delete' the timer. The user can also create new timers from the main window. My intention was to store the timers in the singleton class DataStore and bind to there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, by using `Take` (or any of the LINQ methods) you get a straight `IEnumerable` back. When you have bound to it, there is no `INotifyCollectionChanged` so changes to the collection will not cause the UI to update.

There's no real workaround due to the lack of `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Your best bet is to raise `PropertyChanged` against your "subset" property when you add/remove items to force the UI to renumerate the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "subset" property? Would that be the `TypeACollection` property?

Comment: @ChrisWalters That would be "GetFirstFiveTypeACollection" in your first example

Comment: Okay so i have added this, I believe correctly however i am finding that the PropertyChanged event handler is null and therefore not being fired. would this be a DataContext issue perhaps? Sorry if this seems obvious I'm still learning the ropes with bindings!

Comment: @ChrisWalters If `PropertyChanged` is null then it is very likely you forgot to set your `DataContext`, yes.

Comment: Most likely I've done something stupid wrong but I've edited the question based on the issues I'm now having with `PropertyChanged` being Null.

Comment: @ChrisWalters What is the nature of the static `DATA_STORE` property?

Comment: The DATA_STORE property is the singleton instance of my DataStore class. Possibly not the correct way to go about doing this but I was unsure of another way to ensure only a single instance of the DataStore class was created

Comment: @ChrisWalters It may be an issue with how you set up your singleton then. Everything else looks right at first glance.

Comment: I've added the singleton instance definition to the end of the question, I don't think there's anything wrong there though

Comment: @ChrisWalters Oh, I just realized you are setting stuff *before* calling `InitializeComponent` try setting the context *after* that method call (which should always be first)

Comment: Unfortunately this just causes a binding error for the ContextMenu ItemsSource and no change to the ItemsControl implementation

Comment: @ChrisWalters If that causes a binding error that means you are making progress! Before it just wasn't seeing anything to bind to. Now its telling you where your mistake is.

Comment: Marked as answer, the reason behind my issues with PropertyChanged event being null was that I had in fact somewhere throughout this removed and forgotten that I had removed INotifyPropertyChanged from my class declaration - Yup.. thats how stupid it was! haha Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this using a CollectionView

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    CollectionView _mostRecentDocuments;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Documents = new ObservableCollection<Document>();
        _mostRecentDocuments = new CollectionView(Documents);
        _mostRecentDocuments .Filter = x => Documents.Take(5).Contains(x);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Document> Documents { get; private set; }    

    public CollectionView MostRecentDocuments
    {
        get 
        {
            return _mostRecentDocuments;
        }
    }
}
```